# Python retorno de referência de variável

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quando definimos uma váriavel, basicamente estamos nomeando um endereço de memória, segue um script que representa minha dúvida:

```
class Spam:

    _value = []

    @classmethod
    def value(cls):
        return cls._value

>>> Spam.value()
[]
```

Até aqui tudo bem mas o problema é que o método de classe, retorna uma referência a uma váriavel definida até então como `"privada"`, agora posso fazer:

```
>>> var = Spam.value()
>>> var.append(5)
>>> Spam.value()
[5]
>>> var is Spam.value()
True
```

Em alguns códigos que estou lendo eles evitam retornar uma referência a própria váriavel, e retornam uma cópia da mesma da seguinte forma:

```
class Spam:

    _value = []

    @classmethod
    def value(cls):
        return cls._value.copy()

>>> Spam.value()
[]
>>> var = Spam.value()
>>> var.append(5)
>>> var
[5]
>>> Spam.value()
>>> []
>>> var is Spam.value()
False
```

Existe alguma outra forma de se evitar o retorno da referência em Python?

Answer (score 2):

> Quando definimos uma váriavel, basicamente estamos nomeando um endereço de memória

Isto está incorreto, serve para outras linguagens, mas não para o python.

Em python, não existem variáveis. O que existem são **nomes**; A melhor analogia que encontrei são etiquetas de papel com um nome escrito.

Em python, não existem diferentes valores. Só existe **um único tipo de valor**, que é ***"referência"***. Em python, as variáveis (nomes) não representam endereços de memória como em algumas outras linguagens. Os **nomes** só guardam **referências**, quem aloca e usa a memória são os objetos em si e **não os nomes**.

Resumindo, na verdade o que temos são **nomes** e **referências**. Cada **nome** guarda um valor que é uma **referência** a um objeto.

Quando um objeto não tem mais nenhuma referência a ele, ele é removido da memória e o espaço que ele ocupava é automaticamente liberado.

Por exemplo:

```
x = 5
```

Após executar a linha acima, `x` é declarado como um nome que possui uma referência ao objeto do tipo `int` **`5`**

```
y = x
```

Agora, `y` é outro nome que possui uma referência ao **mesmo objeto** que x. Neste ponto temos **somente um** objeto na memória, o `5`; Temos dois nomes `x` e `y` ambos possuem referências ao mesmo objeto `5`.

```
x = x + 1
```

Agora estamos efetuando uma operação de soma, ou seja, `int.__add__(x, 1)` que **cria** e retorna um **novo** objeto do tipo `int`, o **`6`**. A partir desse ponto o `x` possui uma referência a esse novo objeto `int`. O nome `y` continua se referindo ao objeto `5`. Temos portanto dois nomes e dois objetos na memória.

A situação complica quando se usa objetos mutáveis como listas:

```
a = []
b = a
a.append('Teste')
```

No exemplo acima, só existe uma única lista, criada na primeira linha desse pedaço de código. O método `append()` **não cria** uma nova lista, ele **modifica** a lista existente que se refere, então, você continua tendo dois nomes `a` e `b` se referindo ao mesmo objeto.

```
def func(x):
    x = 2

a = []
func(a)
```

Se a passagem fosse por referência, `x = 2` alteraria `a`; porém, a passagem é por valor, e o valor é uma referência. `x = 2` simplesmente faz com que o nome local `x` se refira a outro objeto, o `2`; O nome `a` continua se referindo à lista `[]`. É impossível alterar o valor de `a` (que é uma referência) através do parâmetro `x`, pois essa referência foi passada **por valor** para dentro da função `func`.

Você pode usar a referência passada para modificar o objeto em si, se ele for mutável, mas não pode usá-la para modificar a quem o nome que foi passado se refere.

Em python, **todas as passagens de parâmetro** e **todos os retornos** são por **valor** porém **esse valor é sempre uma referência**! Não é o mesmo que passar por referência, pois é impossível, de dentro da função, alterar a referência do nome que foi passado como parâmetro.

> Existe alguma outra forma de se evitar o retorno da referência em Python?

No seu primeiro exemplo, o `return` está retornando o **valor** associado ao nome `_value`, mas esse valor é uma referência à lista criada anteriormente:

```
return cls._value
```

Ou seja, essa forma de funcionamento faz parte da linguagem e não há como modificá-la. Todas as passagens são por valor e todos os valores serão sempre referências.

Answer (score 0):

O que queremos é basicamente fazer lista_2 = lista_1 sem que lista_2 seja uma referência a lista_1, ou seja, queremos copiar apenas os valores.

Outra solução além do copy() é usar a função deepcopy():

```
from copy import deepcopy

lista_1 = [1,4]
lista_2 = deepcopy(lista_1)
lista_2.append('mudei aqui')

>>> print('lista_1:', lista_1)
lista_1: [1, 4]
>>> print('lista_2:', lista_2)
lista_2: [1, 4, 'mudei aqui']
```

Outro jeito de copiar apenas os valores de uma lista é:

```
lista_1 = []
lista_2 = lista_1[:]
lista_2.append('mudei aqui')

>>> print('lista_1:', lista_1)
lista_1: []
>>> print('lista_2:', lista_2)
lista_2: ['mudei aqui']
```

Usando a sua classe, ficaria:

```
class Spam:

    _value = []

    @classmethod
    def value(cls):
        return cls._value[:]
        #OU return deepcopy(cls._value)
```

Basicamente a resposta se resume a: copie os valores (valor a valor) e não o objeto. Podemos até fazer uma função para isso (já que o método `lista_1[:]` não funciona para matrizes), mas o copy() e o deepcopy() já resolvem...

```
def copia_lista(lista):
    lista_copia = []
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        lista_copia.append(lista[i])
    return lista_copia

def copia_matriz(matriz):
    matriz_copia = []
    for i in range(0, len(matriz)):
        linha_copia = []
        for j in range(0, len(matriz[i])):
            linha_copia.append(matriz[i][j])
        matriz_copia.append(linha_copia)
    return matriz_copia

class Spam:

    _value = []

    @classmethod
    def value(cls):
        return copia_lista(cls._value)
```

Comment: A sua resposta está errada. No exemplo que diz *"Porém cuidado ao usar essa função"* o código não se comporta do jeito que você colocou na resposta. O `copy` é o suficiente nesse caso, não é necessário usar `deepcopy` já que não tem listas dentro de listas.

Comment: @nosklo, realmente, me enganei com os prints e acabei falando bobagem. Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Se você escrever:

```
a = []
b = a
a.append(5)
print(a)
print(b)
```

'a' será sempre igual a 'b'. não importa as mudanças que sejam feitas.

Para corrigir isso, você pode usar o método copy():

```
a = []
b = a.copy()
a.append(5)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Desse jeito, será criada uma outra lista e 'a' e 'b' serão objetos distintos.