# Como fazer para modificar uma variavel dentro de uma definiçao sem globalizar a variavel?

Tags: python

Preciso modificar uma variável dentro de uma definição sem globalizar a variável porque assim eu posso uzar a mesma definição com variáveis diferentes.

Eu já tentei o código seguinte:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> def f(mmm):
        mmm = 1
        return mmm

>>> f(n)
>>> 1
>>> print(n)
>>> 0
```

> Mesmo depois de executar a definição, a variável n continua com o valor de antes, oque eu posso fazer?

Comment: Eu acho que é melhor você atribuir o retorno da função f a variável n. Ou seja n = f(n)

Answer (score 1):

De fato, sem usar variável global, não é possível fazer o que você quer.

Até porque, se eu fizer isso:

```
def f(mmm):
    mmm = 1
    return mmm

f(10)
```

Repare que chamei a função passando um valor diretamente, em vez de usar uma variável (`f(10)`) - se fosse possível modificar a variável de fora, o que seria alterado nesse caso? O `10`? Não faz sentido.

Claro que algumas linguagens permitem que o valor da variável seja alterado dentro da função, mas o Python não foi feito assim.

A [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) cita algumas formas de contornar isso. No seu caso, a mais simples parece ser simplesmente pegar o retorno da função e atribuí-lo na própria variável:

```
n = f(n)
```

---

Para complementar o assunto, sugiro que leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443427/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59437/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/321739/112052).

Comment: muito obrigado!

Comment: @FelipeMercês Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema